# Props passed via React Router Render comes as undefined in Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass data from state to a component via Route as props. I have used render api to pass the props to the component. But the props come as undefined! Here is the code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SummaryPage from "../../Layout/SummaryPage/SummaryPage";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ContactData from "./ContactData/ContactData";

class Checkout extends Component {
  state = {
    ingredients: null,
    price: 0,
  };

  // Parse the query Params when the component is mounted
  componentWillMount() {
    // Getting the query
    const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);

    // Ingredients as an empty object
    let ingredients = {};
    let price = 0;

    // Looping through the query entries and setting ingredient's value and key to the object
    for (let param of query.entries()) {
      if (param[0] === "price") {
        price = param[1];
      } else {
        ingredients[param[0]] = +param[1];
      }
    }

    // Updating the state
    this.setState({ ingredients: ingredients, totalPrice: price });
  }

  // Cancel checkout and go back to builder
  checkoutCancelledHandler = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack();
  };

  checkoutContinuedHandler = () => {
    this.props.history.replace("/checkout/contact-data");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* SummaryPage */}
        <SummaryPage
          ingredients={this.state.ingredients}
          checkoutCancelled={this.checkoutCancelledHandler}
          checkoutContinued={this.checkoutContinuedHandler}
        />

        <Route
          path={this.props.match.path + "/contact-data"}
          render={(props) => (
            <ContactData
              {...props}
              ingredients={this.state.ingredients}
              price={this.state.totalPrice}
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Checkout;
```

I have tried all possible solutions but it didn't work. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accessing the query string incorrectly. You need to access your search params from the global **document** object.

Try:

```
const query = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
```

Then you can access your params like this:

```
const price = query.get('price');
const ingredients = query.get('ingredients');
```

or

```
for (let p of query) {
  console.log(p);
}
```

More details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams